# How do I remove built-in applications from win8

Tags: windows-8, uninstall, windows-store-app

I purchased a new laptop that (unfortunately) comes with Win8.
I would like to learn whether and how I can remove some of the pre-installed (built-in) applications that Win8 comes with.

To be more specific, I don't any of the kindle, ebay, netflix, finance junk on the machine.

I searched the i-net for an answer. And I found this:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/deploymentguys/archive/2012/10/26/removing-built-in-applications-from-windows-8.aspx

I would like to learn whether there is a way to use the Win 8 interface (e.g. Control Panel) to remove those.

I don't see kindle, ebay, netflix or finance under the list of installed programs.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to right click on it from the modern UI and hit 'uninstall'.  Or touch and hold if you don't have a mouse.[image: uninstall win 8 program]

Comment: Hahaha... I am just slapping my forehead. I installed Classic Shell as soon as I turned the computer on so I didn't realize that the uninstall option was available under the "modern-ui".

Either way, thanks so much, Ian. Very helpful!